# Is $\Omega=D_n(K) \cap Gl_n(K) $an open set?

Tags: matrices, topological-vector-spaces

let $D_n(K)$ the set of diagonalizable matrix and $Gl_n(K)$ the set of inversible ones.

is $\Omega=D_n(K) \cap Gl_n(K) $ an open set ?

I can see that $D_n(K)$ is not an open set and $Gl_n(K)$ is open but that doesnt show anything.

Comment: I don't immediately see why $D_n(K) $ is not open, but if it isn't it's highly unlikely that it contains an open set, so the intersection would not be open.

Comment: why the intersection would not be open ?

Comment: The intersection is an open set contained in both subsets if it is open. If $D_n(K) $ doesn't contain an open set, then there is no such open set so it can't be open.

Comment: What's $K{}{}$?

Comment: What is $K$? Are we taking Zariski open or is it real or complex numbers?

Comment: i mean by K=R or C

Comment: @MattSamuel $D_n(\Bbb C)$ does contain non-empty open sets: namely the set of matrices $A$ such that the resultant of $\det(A-tI)$ and $\frac d{dt}[\det(A-tI)]$ is not $0$. (I.e. the matrices with $n$ distinct complex egenvalues)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the set of diagonalizable invertible matrices is not open. Consider
the matrix    $$  \begin{pmatrix}    1 &\epsilon\\    0 & 1            \end{pmatrix} ,       $$
which is diagonalizable if and only if $\epsilon=0.$